# Github Actions "on push" trigger - "path" argument not working with patterns/wildcards

Tags: github, yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, devops

My GitHub Action is set up to be triggered on push.  It works fine when I don't use a `path:` argument (or I hardcode file paths in it), but it does not work if I use a pattern or wildcard.

Here is the relative portion of my Action:

```
name: "Publish YAML files"
on: 
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - main-github-test
    paths:
      - '**.yaml'
      - '**.yml'
```

The expectation is that my Action will get triggered whenever any file in my repository with the .yaml or .yml extension is modified and pushed to either or the two specified branches.  My assumption is that this wildcard searches recursively throughout my repository from the root to the bottom.

But this is not happening.

If I hardcode specific paths (e.g. docs/myfile.yml), it works fine.  But somehow it doesn't like my pattern/wildcard, even though I'm doing everything "the right way" according to GitHub's own documentation (see [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore)).

What am I doing wrong?

What I tried:

- The following `paths:` argument in my Action:

```
    paths:
      - '**.yaml'
      - '**.yml'
```

Expected behavior:

- My Action is triggered whenever a .yaml or .yml file is modified/committed/pushed to the specified branches.

Actual behavior.

- Action is not triggered.  Instead I must use hardcoded paths or omit the `paths:` argument entirely.

Comment: Can you add a closing quote to the second element in paths and try it again?

Comment: @Sascha thanks for the suggestion.  It didn't fix the problem.  It turns out that my Action already had the closing quote; my question itself had the typo (when I copy/pasted. I didn't have the closing quite selected ).

Comment: I know it might seem like an obvious question, but I ask because what you have in the example is entirely valid and should work, and you still have the `main-github-test` condition in there -- is it possible that either the path filters haven't been merged to your head branch and you're testing them in another branch without them being on the head branch, or that you're testing the path filters on the `main-github-test` branch? Even `'**.ya?ml'` should work as a sole condition for both. I imagine that something else must be the case as I can use these filters just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
name: "Publish YAML files"
on: 
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - main-github-test
    paths:
      - '**/*.yaml'
      - '**/*.yml'
```

It will catch all `yaml` and `yml` files.

You can read about globbing [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-09-30-github-actions-event-filtering-updates/)

Comment: @CB_at_Swivel could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?